# How to render another page in Main page using ajax in yii2

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii2

I want to render a page using partial render. i want to do it using ajax how i will be able to do it.
I m new to ajax so i dont know more about it .

This is the page that i want to render

```
<td><?= Html::input('text' , 'name' = '[DefVendors]["name"]' ); ?></td>
<td><?= Html::input('text' , 'name' = '[DefVendors]["address"]' ); ?></td>
<td><?= Html::input('text' , 'name' = '[DefVendors]["email"]' ); ?></td>
<td><?= Html::input('text' , 'name' = '[DefVendors]["contact"]' ); ?></td>
<td><?= Html::input('text' , 'name' = '[DefVendors]["bank_name"]' ); ?></td>
<td><?= Html::input('text' , 'name' = '[DefVendors]["bank_accountno"]' ); ?></td>
<td><?= Html::dropDwonList($modelVendors , 'company_id' , arrayHelper::map(defCompanies::find()->all() , 'id' ,'name' , ['prompt' => 'Select Company'])) ?></td>
```

and here this should be rendered in the

```
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple example.

Controller

```
class ExampleController extends Controller {

    public function actionIndex()
    {
        return $this->ajaxResponse(true, $this->renderPartial('your_view',[]));
    }

    private function ajaxResponse($success = true, $content = '')
    {
        $response = [
            'success' => $success,
            'content' => $content

        ];
        echo json_encode($response);
        return $success;
    }
}
```

JavaScript

```
$.get('example/index', (html) => {
     var response = JSON.parse(html);
     $('#your-selector').html(response.content);
});
```